# Bootstrap-multiselect is checked after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using [Bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin and can't get my head around how to reset all option to be deselected after I reload the page. When I just hit reload in my FF - page reload but the selected option stays.

I've tried following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {

        function getgraph(checked, element) {
                var data ={blablabla}

                $("#get_graph").load("get_graph", data);
        }


        function selector_onchange(element, checked) {              
                getgraph(checked, element.val());
        };

        $('#multiselect').multiselect({
            enableHTML: true,
            onChange: selector_onchange
        });
        $('#multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
        $('#multiselect').multiselect('refresh');
        getgraph(null, null);


    });

</script>
```

Comment: `.multiselect('deselectAll', true);` should work. have u checked if your `getgraph(null, null);` call if giving some error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do this like it is said in documentation
[.multiselect('refresh')](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods)

I suppose you missed this:

```
$(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
```

Comment: changing `$('#multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', true);` to `$('#multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', false);` actually helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

on page load do something like:

```
$('#multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
```

see docs http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods
.multiselect('deselectAll', justVisible)

Hope that helps